# Why won't this ASP-EMAIL form won't send email

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I recently got helped to fix my ASP EMAIL script but now I get this compiling error when trying to send email from the CONTACT FORM .. The script is below the ERROR MESSAGE

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30807: 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported.

Source Error:

Line 10:     if Request("Send") <> "" Then 
Line 11:
Line 12:         Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender") 
Line 13:
Line 14:         objMail.Host = strHost

Source File: E:\HostingSpaces\dma\myuniversalcare.com\wwwroot\contact-us\Default.aspx    Line: 12

Here is the script:

```
<% 
    Session.CodePage = 65001 

Dim strHost, objMail, strToAddress, txtMsg 

    ' Change this to your own SMTP server 
    strHost = "localhost" 

    if Request("Send") <> "" Then 

        Set objMail = Server.CreateObject("Persits.MailSender") 

        objMail.Host = strHost 

        objMail.From = "info@persits.com"           ' From address 
        objMail.FromName = "AspEmail Live Demo"     ' optional 

        strToAddress = Trim(Request("txtTo")) 

        ' To prevent header injection attack 
        strToAddress = Replace( strToAddress, " ", "" ) 
        strToAddress = Replace( strToAddress, chr(13), "" ) 
        strToAddress = Replace( strToAddress, chr(10), "" ) 

        ' To address, 2nd argument omitted. 
        objMail.AddAddress strToAddress 

        ' Message subject 
        objMail.Subject = objMail.EncodeHeader( Request("txtSubject"), "UTF-8" ) 

        ' Enable Unicode 
        objMail.ContentTransferEncoding = "Quoted-Printable" 
        objMail.CharSet = "UTF-8" 

        ' Message body 
        objMail.Body = Request("txtBody") 

        ' Include a disclaimer 
        objMail.Body = objMail.Body & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & "-----------------------------------" & chr(13) & chr(10) & chr(13) & chr(10) & "This message was generated by the AspEmail live demo on-line application. Persits Software, Inc. is not responsible for its content." 

        On Error Resume Next 
        objMail.Send ' Send message 

        If Err = 0 then      
            txtMsg = "<font color=green>Success! Message sent to " & strToAddress + ".</font>" 
        Else         
            txtMsg = "<font color=red>Error occurred: " + err.Description + "</font>" 
        End If 

    End If 
%> 

<HTML> 
<HEAD> 

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 

<TITLE>AspEmail Live Demo: Unicode-enabled Message Sending</TITLE> 
</HEAD> 
<BODY style="font-family: arial narrow; font-size: 10pt"> 

<h2>AspEmail Live Demo: Unicode-enabled Message Sending</h2> 

<P>  


<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="demo_simple.asp"> 

<TABLE CELLSPACING=2 CELLPADDING=2 BGCOLOR="#E0E0E0" style="border: 1pt black solid; border-collapse: collapse"> 
    <TR> 
        <TD>To:</TD> 
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" size="40" NAME="txtTo" VALUE="<% = Server.HtmlEncode(Request("txtTo")) %>"></TD> 
    </TR> 
    <TR> 
        <TD>Subject:</TD> 
        <TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" size="40" NAME="txtSubject" VALUE="<% = Server.HtmlEncode(Request("txtSubject")) %>"></TD> 
    </TR> 
    <TR> 
        <TD valign="top">Body:</TD> 
        <TD><TEXTAREA NAME="txtBody" Rows="10" Cols="40"><% = Server.HtmlEncode(Request("txtBody")) %></TEXTAREA></TD> 
    </TR> 
    <TR> 
        <TD COLSPAN=2><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Send" VALUE="Send Message"></TD> 
    </TR> 

</TABLE> 

<P> 

<% = txtMsg %> 

</FORM> 

</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged c# and asp.net?  This is classic ASP, as different from asp.net as it is from Java Server Pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using aspx you can not use set . You are having a ASP code in to aspx page .